# How to pass generic to method which require its superclass?

Tags: java

I have some class

```
public final class Response<T> {

}
```

And I have superclass

```
public class BaseResponse {

}
```

From superclass I inherit

```
public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse{

}
```

Later I create object `Response<LoginResponse> myResponse` and I want to pass this object to following method, which works only with superclass method and fields:

```
public static boolean responseIsValid(Response<BaseResponse> response, Context context) {
     return false;
}
```

And I am getting `wrong argument type` error. How to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `Response<BaseResponse>` with wildcard `Response<? extends BaseResponse>`

```
public static boolean responseIsValid(Response<? extends BaseResponse> response, Context context) {
   return false;
}
```

of course if `LoginResponse` really extends `BaseResponse`

```
public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse { }
```